# Using Flutter Provider with Navigator

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I've come to Flutter from Swift. I'm currently having trouble trying to access a UserModel after pushing onto the navigation stack.

How can I access `Provider` once I have used `Navigator`?

When I push a new widget through `CupertinoPageRoute` I get the error 'Could not find the correct `Provider<UserModel>` above this `Consumer<UserModel>` widget.

I have read numerous answers to similar questions stating that the provider should go above the `MaterialApp`. This wouldn't work in my scenario as the app must check for a logged in user prior to creating the UserModel from Firebase. It also seems to go against what I've seen in Flutter videos that `ChangeNotifiers` should be as far down the widget tree as possible for performance reasons.

**My basic app logic**

`MaterialApp` checks for a `Firebase User`. If there isn't one, it presents the `LoginPage`. If there is, it returns a ChangeNotifierProvider which listens to the user object in Firebase and in term presents the `HomePage`. The `HomePage` has bottom navigation and the widgets displayed here can use the provider.

If a user clicks a button to edit their profile, I push the `ProfilePageOne` using the `Navigator.push` method. When trying to access to the provider I get the error.

I've thought about passing a User object from one page to the next but I feel that defeats the object of having `Provider`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you get error that Provider is not found on Particular class or widget then you can wrap your widget with provider and give your provider class. Basic concept of Provider is you need to give Provider with common parent of the child so if you see widget tree and see that there are multiple children with common parent then you can give provider to that parent and access provider in children without any error you get at this time.

```
    return Provider(
      create: (context) {
        return your_provider_class_name();
      },
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: const Class name(),
        theme: ThemeData(
          useMaterial3: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

In above example I wrap provider above the material app because through out the App life cycle material is not dispose so we can easily access all the things related to provider easily.